# SharedPreference Before oncreate for global variable

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner, I want to save user settings , but the settings variables used is globally declared

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var ASPECTRATIO =if(!getPref("AspectRatio")) AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9  else AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3   //this varible is used all over methods
    
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility", "InflateParams")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     }
        fun getPref(key:String): Boolean {
            val sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences("Settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return sharedPrefs.getBoolean(key,false)
        }
        fun putPref(key: String,value : Boolean){
            val sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences("Settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            with(sharedPrefs.edit()){
                putBoolean(key, value).apply()
            }
        }
        .....
```

this produces nullpointerexception. I think there is no context before onCreate() as the global variable initialize before that.

Is there a solution that I can use sharedPreference and also assign values from shared prefrenece before oncreate .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic solution would be to use `lazy` initialization:

```kotlin
class MainActivity {
    private val aspectRatio by lazy { getPref(...) }
    
    //...
}
```

This way, `aspectRatio` initialization would be deferred to the first use of it (which should be when Context is already available)

Comment: But I need that as var not val , I will change that variable frequently.

Comment: If I treid to access sharedpreference with lazy{} it says nullpointerexception .

Comment: If you want to change it, declare it as `private lateinit var aspectRatio: ...` and initialize it in onCreate. You can change it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "SharedPrefName",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    if (!sharedPreferences.getString("name", "").toString().isEmpty()) {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define it as `var` with some default value initially, then modify it in `onCreate` before it's first use or even before `super.onCreate()`

```
private var aspectRatio = AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3 //default value

override fun onCreate(savedStateInstance: Bundle?){
     aspectRatio = if(!getPref("AspectRatio")) AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9 else AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3 
     super.onCreate(savedStateInstance)
}
```

Comment: I tried but I can't use var , idle asks me to change to val error.

Comment: If I treid to access sharedpreference with lazy{} it says nullpointerexception .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the sharedPreferencies like that:

```
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name_of_param", param).apply()

    return sharedPreferences.getString("name_of_param", null)
```

Comment: Context will be null at that time .

Answer (score 0):

on Kotlin:

1. Create a global methods to get access to context:

> ```
> private var appContext: Context? = null
> ```

```
val application: Context
>         get() = appContext ?: initAndGetAppCtxWithReflection()
>     
>     @SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
>     private fun initAndGetAppCtxWithReflection(): Context {
>         val activityThread = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread")
>         val ctx = activityThread.getDeclaredMethod("currentApplication").invoke(null) as Context
>         appContext = ctx
>         return ctx
```

2. Create Cache class to initialize shared preferences

> `

```
class CacheData constructor(name: String? = "Yaku_lab_preferences_common") {

    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = application.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun hasKey(key: String): Boolean = sharedPreferences.contains(key)

    fun clear(){
        sharedPreferences.edit().clear()?.apply()
    }

    fun remove(key: String) {
        if(hasKey(key))
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key)?.apply()
    }

    fun setInt(key: String, value: Int) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(key, value)?.apply()
    }
    fun getInt(key: String, defaultValue: Int): Int {
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue)
    }
    fun getInt(key: String): Int? {
        return if(hasKey(key)){
            sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun setFloat(key: String, value: Float) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat(key, value)?.apply()
    }
    fun getFloat(key: String, defaultValue: Float): Float {
        return sharedPreferences.getFloat(key, defaultValue)
    }
    fun getFloat(key: String): Float? {
        return if(hasKey(key)){
            sharedPreferences.getFloat(key, 0f)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun setLong(key: String, value: Long) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(key, value)?.apply()
    }
    fun getLong(key: String, defaultValue: Long): Long {
        return sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue)
    }
    fun getLong(key: String): Long? {
        return if(hasKey(key)){
            sharedPreferences.getLong(key, 0)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun setString(key: String, value: String) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value)?.apply()
    }
    fun getString(key: String, defaultValue: String): String {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue) ?: defaultValue
    }
    fun getString(key: String): String? {
        return if(hasKey(key)){
            sharedPreferences.getString(key, "")
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun getBoolean(key: String, defaultValue: Boolean): Boolean {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue)
    }
    fun getBoolean(key: String): Boolean? {
        return if(hasKey(key)){
            sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
    fun setBoolean(key: String, value: Boolean) {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value)?.apply()
    }
}
```

`

3. Create a class for accessing shared preferences

> `

```
class MyPreferences {

    val prefs = CacheData()

    var emailRegistered: String
        get()      = prefs.getString("email", "")
        set(value) = prefs.setString("email", value)
}
```

`

4. Accessing or setting data for wherever activity could be easy

> `

```
MyPreferences().emailRegistered = "Hola mundo"

        println("REspuesta: ${MyPreferences().emailRegistered}")
```

`

5. If you don't know where is the context here is an example
   my custom class to get context globally

> `

```
lateinit var ctx      : Context
open class MyApp(): Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ctx   = this
    }
}
```

`

5. Also it says if you use a custom class you need to modify the manifest

> `

```
<application
        android:name=".root.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Yakulap">
```

`